# What are some properties of Delone sets that come from Barlow packings of spheres?

Tags: tiling, sphere-packing

Given a Barlow packing of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by balls with at most a finite number of different radii, the centers of the balls will form a Delone set in $\mathbb{R}^n.$

For a highest density sphere packing, or at least a Barlow packing of highest density among Barlow packings, must the corresponding Delone set be a Meyer set? A Patterson set? In the cases of dimensions 2 and 3 where the optimal packing using a single radius is known, the sets can be chosen to be lattices.

I looked for papers exploring this connection and could only find this one https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/PUBLIS/publications/REF_678.pdf, which is good, but doesn't address the big picture questions above.

EDIT: As the comments indicate, we should restrict to Barlow packings. In this case the Delone sets always appear to be of finite local complexity.

Comment: I am particularly interested in whether the topology and dynamics of tiling spaces cold be used to prove results about sphere packings. Would the tiling spaces associated to optimal sphere packings need to have extra symmetry or could we give restrictions on the dimensions of their cohomology?

Comment: I had thought this was a somewhat interesting question... Is there anything I can do to make it more answerable?

Comment: Regarding "in the cases of dimensions 2 and 3 where the optimal packing is known, the sets end up being lattices," I assume you're not talking about a finite number of different radii any more but about a single radius.

Comment: Yes, in that case I was referring to packings with a single radius. I will edit the question to reflect that. 

Comment: I'm not familiar in detail with the terms you use (finite local complexity, etc.), but I suspect that not much more can be said for optimal packing of spheres of different radii than can be said for tiling with general tile sets. In the latter case, note that the tiling can end up being as complex as the output from an arbitrary Turing machine (see Wang tiles).

Comment: Finite local complexity means that for any fixed radius R, there are only finitely many patterns up to translation that appear in a ball of radius R. This condition ensures that the tiling space is compact. The other conditions have to do with properties of the dynamical spectrum of the tiling space, but intuitively they correspond to the pattern having some sort of "long range order."

Comment: Also keep in mind that a sphere packing in three dimensions, even if it achieves the highest density and is saturated (in the sense that there is no space to add an extra ball without moving the others) can fail to have finite local complexity. You probably need a stronger definition of saturation.

Comment: Ah, so while the density of any 3 dimensional packing cannot be larger than a periodic packing, there are other known packings achieving that density which are not themselves periodic? And the centers of those packings may not form a Delone set of finite local complexity?

Comment: I believe that's right: you can have pockets of arbitrary (saturated) arrangements as long as the total volume of those pockets have zero density. However, under the most stringent definitions of saturation, you can have only Barlow stackings, and those, I believe have finite local complexity. For ideas about what it means for a packing to be saturated, see Kuperberg "Notions of Denseness" (arXiv:math/9908003).

Comment: To be clear, "Barlow packing" means a stacking of close-packed triangular layers in ways other than h.c.p. or f.c.c. It does not, to my knowledge, means packings that are saturated under the strongest notions of saturation.

Comment: You're right, changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider the Barlow lattices, these are obtained by taking
planar hexagonal packings of spheres, and nesting them together
in layers. For each layer, there are two possible ways of placing
the layer above it:
[image]
<sub>(source: [cnx.org](https://cnx.org/content/m16927/latest/graphics15.png))</sub>

Let's normalize the Barlow lattices to have one common layer (the A-layer).
The heights of the (centers of spheres of the) other layers will be multiples of the height of a
tetrahedron, so are the same for each Barlow lattice. The centers of the vertices of the next
layer above have two possibilities, one with projection given by the B-circles, and one
given by the C-circles (these are symmetric under a transformation
preserving A-circles, so let's assume the next layer is the B-circles).
Then the next layer can have projection either the C-circles or the A-circles
(the diagram corresponds to the face-centered cubic lattice, so the pattern
there is ABCABC...). Thus, we see that for any Barlow lattice D, the
differences $D-D$ will be a subset of the superposition of 3 face-centered cubic
lattices which have the A-,B-,C-layers at each level, and thus will be a discrete set. So it will be a Meyer set (I'm
going by the [definition of a Meyer set](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1400744) as a discrete set $M$ such that $M-M$ is
also Delone).

Comment: Thanks! It seems like this question hasn't yet been fully explored...